How do manufacturers tell us about the direction in which the yield stress test has been done?
It's my first year studying materials science and engineering at university.
Based on what we have been told, there are lots of materials out there that are not isotropic considering some properties such as yield stress, ... .
My question is: If that's the case( which seems completely logical to me ), why is there only one number written on manufactured materials determining, for example, the yield stress?
Shouldn't it be mentioned that for what direction the number is?

What materials are you looking at and what sources are you using

It's your job to get the info you need. You can buy on the cheap and generate the data yourself, or you can buy from someone that partners with you and can supply the supporting data you need. If all this stuff was just out there, you wouldn't have a job. It's not just about asking the right questions, its about having the means to obtain the answers.

Phil Sweet  I think you have misunderstood my question or maybe it's the way I asked it. What I want to know is what exactly that number shows and for what direction it is. For sure the  experiment that is done to measure the yield stress was done in a specific direction. How do manufacterers tell us about that?

Material testing is done in accordance with standardized tests.  You report the results of those tests. If you want to know what the number represents, you must research the test method.

Phil Sweet Thank you.

Isn't it possible that the material of concern with just one yield stress value is isotropic?
